# Plumbing inspection passed but pressure drops to zero overnight

Tags: plumbing

I'm having a new home built. The plumbers pressurized the system with air to about 90 lbs. It dropped overnight to almost zero. When the inspector came it was zero so he failed them.

Then they came back out and pressurized the system just before the inspector came the next day and the inspector passed the system. By the next morning the pressure was zero again. Is this normal? Am I going to have a leak when we put water into the home?

Comment: The air had to go somewhere, right?  Water is going to find a way out as well.

Comment: It is suppose to be a close system.  So unless someone open the system(open a faucet), then there is a leak.

Answer (score 24):

**That would be fraud**, and the plumber should/could be penalized for doing it. Contact the inspector directly and share what you've told us. Have the problem fixed, ideally by a *different* plumber. Backcharge the original plumber for any time and expense (or withhold final payment).